# How do I implement additional packages autocomplete-R, Atom Text editor?

Tags: r, json, autocomplete, atom-editor

Autocomplete-R only recognizes and provides r-studio like completion for base packages. I would like r-studio like completion for user installed packages like lme4. The Autocomplete-R author provides a vague description of how to do this: https://github.com/guillaumechaumet/autocomplete-R .

However, I do not know how this works or if there is a better workaround.

Here is the git-hub read me file recommendation from https://github.com/guillaumechaumet/autocomplete-R :

Scripts R was made to parse R documentation to a json file.
The default R packages were implemented.

```
print(.packages())
```

To implement more packages you just need to execute

```
source("~/.atom/packages/autocomplete-R/R/packages_new.R")
```

I have tried to create a packages_new.R file of multiple lines library("some_package") within the specified directory. Then ran the second line within my code in atom, but it does nothing to improve autocompletion.

Any help or direction is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, don't have an answer to your direct question, But you can do this with VScode and plugins. It's an amazing text editor (I've tried N++, Atom and Sublime). https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I would like to stick with atom